# How can I add space before some content for the first two elements and hide it

Tags: html, css

I have three elements like this:

```
<div class="mainLinks> 
  <a>A</a> 
  <a>B</a> 
  <a>ABC</a>
</div>
```

I want to add space to first two elements right before the character. Below is what I'm trying to do but the style is not getting applied. But only  `a:before` styles applied with the characters showing. i tried   `content: "    ";` but it is not working too.

```
.mainLinks  a:nth-child(-n+3){
  content: "&nbsp;";
}


.mainLinks  a:before{
  content: "&nbsp;";
}
```

Comment: probably you want this `a:nth-child(-n+3):before { }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a literal space and preserve the white-space.

See below:

```css
.mainLinks a::before {
  content: " ";
  white-space: pre;
}

.mainLinks a:last-child::before {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainLinks"> 
  <a>A</a>
  <a>B</a>
  <a>ABC</a>
</div>
```

Comment: `.mainLinks a::before {
  content: " ";
  white-space: pre;
}` this works!